# node.js heap memory dump, why the String memory is too high?

Tags: node.js, heap-memory, heap-dump

I am having some memory leak in my code. so i took memory snapshot using heapdump nodemodule. 
using heapdump i have fixed something then its fine. But why string buffer size is still too high and its keep on increasing ?

I have attached screen shot of the memory heapdump for my component. the heapdump  file size is 139MB so i cant attach here.  i dont know what other information you guys need to help on this...

[image: String memory list]

[image: Overall memory list]

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: Not yet completely but getting closer. will post once i got complete solution.

Comment: Those strings in the screenshot are the functions that enclose all files you `require()`. Since they are anonymous, every required module gets its own. I wonder, however, why they do not get released. What Node.js version are you using? Are you using native JS or some compile-to-js language (CoffeeScript, TypeScript etc.)?

Comment: Are you doing require() in a loop?

Comment: @TomG No i am not doing anything like that...

Comment: the memory leak solution is null your all objects and array at end of function.  use process.memoryUsage() and check the heapused value. 
If the value is not reducing then u r having some problem. dont consider RSS value

Comment: Also, it may be helpful to know what version of nodejs you are using...  Have you also consider node-inspector?

Comment: I'm having this same issue, you can see here. I'm using Babel.. Amy thoughts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628540/why-is-node-require-cache-filling-up-and-leaking

Answer (score 1):

The [memwatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memwatch) module might help provide some more insight. It will allow you to subscribe to `leak` events

```js
memwatch.on('leak', function(info) { 
console.error('Memory leak detected: ', info); 
});
```

Have a read of [this tutorial](http://www.nearform.com/nodecrunch/self-detect-memory-leak-node/) which does a great job of explaining how to detect the reasons for memory leaks in node.